# covariation of semimartingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

Consider  continuous semimartingales $X,Y,Z$, i.e.

$X=X(0) + A + M$,

where  $A$ is a process of finite variation and M a local martingale, both starting in $0$

I want to proof:
$\langle X + Y , Z \rangle = \langle X,Z\rangle + \langle Y, Z
    \rangle$

Since $\langle X,B \rangle =0 $ if $B$ is of finite variation, the left hand side reads as:

$$ <M_X+M_Y, M_Z>. $$

$M_K$ denotes the local martingale component in the doob meyer decomposition of each process $K$.

The right hand side gets:  $\langle M_X,M_Z \rangle $  + $\langle M_Y,M_Z \rangle $

So I only have to verify this property for the martingale component.

Is that reasonable?
How can I go on from here?

Comment: When you use that $\langle X,B \rangle = 0$ if $B$ is of finite variation, it seems you're already using that the covariation is additive.  What is the definition of $\langle X,Y \rangle$ that you are using?

Comment: @user6247850: The covariation of two semimartingales is defined as the covariation of their local matringale parts.

Comment: How would you proceed from there?

Comment: Okay, and what's the definition of the covariation of two local martingales?

Comment: @user6247850: If $M,N$ are local matringales, then $MN - <M,N>$ is a local martingale, where $<M,N>$  is continous, adapted and of finite variation.

Comment: So if you show $(M_X+M_Y)M_Z - (\langle M_X, M_Z \rangle + \langle M_Y,M_Z \rangle)$ is a local martingale, you will have shown $\langle M_X, M_Z \rangle + \langle M_Y,M_Z \rangle = \langle M_X+M_Y, M_Z \rangle$.  Do you see how to do that?

Comment: @user6247850: I will try to do it. But the argumentation before was ok, that I do not consider the finite variation parts?

Comment: @user6247850:  $M_XM_Z= \frac{1}{4}[(M_X+M_Z)^2 - (M_X+M_Z)^2]$ is a local martingale. By defintion: $$M_X M_Z - <M_X,M_Z>  =\frac{1}{4}[(M_X+M_Z)^2 - <M_X+M_Z>] + \frac{1}{4}[(M_X-M_Z)^2 - <M_X-M_Z>] $$

Comment: The summands are local martingales each. In similar way we can deduce that $M_YM_Z - <M_Y,M_Z>$ is a local martingale. From uniqueness follows the claim?

Comment: Yes, the finite variation parts are ignored by definition.  Your last two comments prove the equivalence of the definition you gave and defining $\langle M,N \rangle := \frac 14 (\langle M+N,M+n \rangle - \langle M-N,M-N \rangle)$, and a similar technique will prove what you asked in the question, but I'm not sure how they directly relate to my hint.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. What is the problem with my proof. How would you do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129552/discussion-between-user6247850-and-alif).